# java, integer isn't used (calculator)

Tags: java, calculator

I am busy making a calculator but somehow the integer isn't used, I don't know why. I try to fix it but I can't find out how to do it. I use a button with a event to calculate the answer, maybe something's wrong with that. Here's my code:
Btw I use Eclipse

```
    package cal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class cal{
    //declare
    JLabel l;
    JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate");
    JTextField f, f1;
    String x, y, answer;
    JTextArea a;
    int answerValue, xValue, yValue;

    //main
    public static void main(String [] args){
        cal c = new cal();
        c.Start();
        //Start method
    }public void Start(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(640,640);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //declare
        l = new JLabel("enter value: ");
        f = new JTextField(10);
        f1 = new JTextField(10);

        //remaining
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        a = new JTextArea(20,50);
        a.setEditable(false);

        calc.addActionListener(new button());

        p.add(l);
        p.add(f);
        p.add(f1);
        p.add(calc);
        p.add(a);

        frame.getContentPane().add(p);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    // Calculate 
    class button implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            x = f.getText();
            y = f1.getText();

            //converting string to integer
            try{
                int xValue= Integer.parseInt(x);
                int yValue = Integer.parseInt(y);
                }catch( NumberFormatException exep){
            exep.printStackTrace();
            }

            answerValue = xValue * yValue;
            String AV =Integer.toString(answerValue);

            System.out.println(answerValue);

            //displaying answer
            a.append(AV + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am talking about the xValue and yValue

Comment: *Which* integer isn't used? It's unclear what you're seeing.

Comment: Additionally, I'd *strongly* recommend that you start following Java naming conventions... it will make your code much easier for the rest of us to read.

Comment: ehm sorry forgot about that :( but xValue and yValue isn't used in the code.

Comment: Is the event handler being called?

Comment: Also, if you are getting some sort of error, include it in your post.

Comment: well no but I now know what I did wrong so thank you all for your help :D

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
try {
    int xValue = Integer.parseInt(x);
    int yValue = Integer.parseInt(y);
} catch (NumberFormatException exep) {
    exep.printStackTrace();
}
```

That's declaring new *local* variables `xValue` and `yValue`, rather than changing the values of your *instance* variables `xValue` and `yValue`.

If you still want the instance variables, just change the code to avoid declaring new local variables:

```
try {
    xValue = Integer.parseInt(x);
    yValue = Integer.parseInt(y);
} catch (NumberFormatException exep) {
    exep.printStackTrace();
}
```

Alternatively - and preferably, unless you really need them elsewhere - you could get rid of the instance variables entirely, and declare the local variables before your try/catch block:

```
int xValue = 0;
int yValue = 0;
try {
    xValue = Integer.parseInt(x);
    yValue = Integer.parseInt(y);
} catch (NumberFormatException exep) {
    exep.printStackTrace();
}
```

Likewise you could get rid of `answerValue` unless you need that elsewhere.

I'd strongly advise you to reconsider your exception "handling" strategy though. You're effectively ignoring the exception and just continuing as if everything was fine...

Comment: I recommend the last approach. Minimizing the scope of variables is something we should always strive for.

Comment: @hfontanez: Absolutely - I'm just not sure whether the OP wanted to use `xValue` and `yValue` elsewhere.

Comment: I would add that, MAYBE, the only variable that should be global is the answer. This is in case the OP wants to perform another operation using the result as one of the operands.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to use `xValue`, you're actually creating a new one. Same with `yValue`.

Remove the `int` before the names before you try to access them, otherwise you're creating new ones, and using them instead.